# How to cycle 100% height pages and URLs after scrolling a threshold amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

How does one implement the beautiful "scroll to view next or previous" feature as seen here:

http://activetheory.net/work/

The page is always 100% of the viewport height.  When scrolling, if you reach a certain threshold, the URL changes and the new content is displayed in the same format.

I'm looking to for a bare bones example on how to cycle 100% height pages and URLs after scrolling a threshold amount.

Comment: please clarify your question ?

Comment: Please visit http://activetheory.net/work/ and scroll down.  Then scroll up.  You'll notice that you are navigating the site.  I'm working on creating my own example to indicate where I'm getting stuck.  Briefly, I'm using individual html pages for each URL and each page is 100% of the height.  I'm having a hard time capturing the scroll event when no elements move on the page.  Perhaps, I must instead have all pages contained within one html file and fake the URL change once scrolled past a certain threshold.  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found the answer!

https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll